# Working with Maven snapshots in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

If Project B has a dependency on Project A.

Do I need to do a maven install on Project A every single time I make a change to one of the classes in A in order for B to see the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you created the projects. If you have a common parent pom, then you won't need to run `mvn install` for one project to see the changes on the other.

If the projects don't share a common parent pom, I think it might be better to configure eclipse manually so it knows that B depends on A, and you'll also need to remove the dependency on the snapshot jar (otherwise you might get funky classloader errors). I have to say that every time that I had projects dependencies like this, the projects shared a common parent.